# How can I get d3 server-side in Meteor?

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I'd like to use a part of d3 server-side in a Meteor app. Specifically, [d3's CSV utilities](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV). However, [the package.js file](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/package.js) only provides d3 to clients.

Does it make sense to use the d3 CSV utilities server-side? If yes, what's the canonical way to make this happen?

Crossposted on forums.meteor.com [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-can-i-get-d3-server-side-in-meteor/2976).

Comment: I've made a small edit to make it clear that when you say "cross posted" you don't mean on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @skrrgwasme thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own package or just download and drop the [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) into your project in a way that makes it accessible server side, as in don't put it in the client or public directories.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Does it make sense to use the d3 CSV utilities server-side? @awatson1978 [provided example code here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-can-i-get-d3-server-side-in-meteor/2976/2).

Comment: Unless it's referencing the DOM, it should be fine. Go look at the code and see if it does.

Answer (score 1):

You could give D3-Node a try. https://github.com/bradoyler/d3-node